# how to configure routes for child controllers in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

1. `Reports` has many `ReportInstances`
2. `ReportInstances` belongs to `Reports`

I would like to have the url `/reports/:report-id/instances` to point to the action `index_by_report_id` inside `ReportInstancesController.php`

How do I configure the `routes.php` accordingly?

**UPDATE:**

I tried nested resources as described here:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-nested-resource-routes

Here are my routes

```
$routes->resources('Reports', [
    'map' => [
        'standard' => [
            'action' => 'standard',
            'method' => 'GET',
        ]
    ]
]);

$routes->resources('Reports', function ($routes) {
    $routes->resources('ReportInstances');
});
```

When I do a `/reports/1/instances`, it goes to ReportsController looking for action 1.

Please advise.

Comment: `resources()` is for RESTful routes... are you actually looking for RESTful routes?

Comment: I want nested routes for RESTful and non RESTful urls. Possible??

Comment: Possible is (pretty much) everything... but, how exactly do imagine this to work like, which URLs do you need to connect as RESTful, and which not?

Comment: Basically I want to have /reports/1/instances to point to an action which will display paginated results of instances that belong to report of id 1.

Ideally this url should be RESTful.

The other one that is needed would be /reports/1/instances/add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this in your `routes.php`

```
$routes->resources('Parents', function ($routes) {
    $routes->resources('Children');
});

$routes->resources('Children');
```

In `ChildrenController.php`,

```
protected function _prepareConditions() {
    $parentId = isset($this->request->params['parent_id']) ? $this->request->params['parent_id'] : null;

    if ($parentId == null) {
        return [];
    }

    return [
        'Children.parent_id' => $parentId
    ];
}

public function index()
{
    $conditions = $this->_prepareConditions();

    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Parents'],
        'conditions' => $conditions
    ];
  // ... and so on
```

You will be able to do the following:

1. /parents/1/children
2. /parents/1/children.json
3. /children
4. /children.json

**Why this works?**

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-nested-resource-routes

tells us that basically to basically retrieve the parent id from the request params.

What it does not say explicitly is that, the routes will then reuse the basic 5 functions: index, add, view, delete, edit even when you nest them under a parent url.

**Why do you still have a separate resources route for the Children?**

This allows the /children and /children.json to work if you need them as well.

**What about add?**

I haven't tried that but I do not foresee any issues with using that as

1. /parents/1/children/add
2. /parents/1/children/add.json
3. /children/add
4. /children/add.json