# CakePHP 3.x how do I include the params in the mapped resources?

Tags: rest, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

this is what I have in my routes:

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->extensions(['json']);
    $routes->resources('CustomerCompanies', [
        'map' => [
            'get_by_account' => [
                'action' => 'get_by_account',
                'method' => 'GET',
            ]
        ]
    ]);
```

This is my method `get_by_account` inside `CustomerCompaniesController.php`:

```
/**
 * Pagination method by Customer Account id
 *
 * @param string|null $id Customer Account id.
 * @return void Redirects to index.
 * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
 */
public function get_by_account($customer_account_id = null)
{

}
```

Relations:

1. `CustomerAccounts` hasMany `CustomerCompanies`
2. `CustomerCompanies` belongsTo `CustomerAccounts`

I want to return a list of CustomerCompanies that belong to a particular CustomerAccount by supplying the CustomerAccount id and I get back in json results.

Do I need to change something in the get_by_account to indicate the param? and if so, how?

**UPDATE**

This is what I saw in the documents:

[image: what i saw in documents]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to define the `:id` route element, which is being [**passed by default**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.1/src/Routing/RouteBuilder.php#L328) (there is currently no way to pass further custom route elements). You can do that either in the array key of your map entry

```
'map' => [
    'get_by_account/:id' => [
        'action' => 'get_by_account',
        'method' => 'GET',
    ]
]
```

or via the `path` option (by default, the key is set as the value for the `path` option)

```
'map' => [
    'get_by_account' => [
        'action' => 'get_by_account',
        'method' => 'GET',
        'path' => 'get_by_account/:id'
    ]
]
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Mapping Additional Resource Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#mapping-additional-resource-routes)**
- **[Source > \Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder::$_resourceMap](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.1/src/Routing/RouteBuilder.php#L51-L57)**

Comment: Does it matter that I use `customer_account_id` in `get_by_account($customer_account_id = null)`? and can I use it for nested resources? E.g. instead of `get_by_account/:id`, I use `accounts/:id/companies` and I place this inside the CustomerAccounts controller?

Comment: I also read the cookbook link you put up, and there is no mention of how to use the key within the same section. Also, I was wondering if I can also put in validations like the e.g. in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#route-elements? You can see that they restrict the `:id` to numeric

Comment: @KimStacks 1.) No. 2.) Maybe, maybe not, depends on what you expect the final URL to look like. Using actual nested resources will create fixed parent paths. 3.) There is, immediately after the first example. 4.) Look at the `id` option for `RouteBuilder::resources()`. If you need to keep the existing ID validation for other routes in the same resource, then you'll have to create, use and pass (`connectOptions`) a custom element (not sure if this works out though).

Comment: Just want to clarify: I have taken a snapshot of the link you gave for the cookbook and placed it in the question. As you can see, the cookbook has a updateALl and deleteAll example. No examples for what you wrote where a `:id` is supplied in the `path` key. Do you think we should add your example into the documents at this section?

Comment: @KimStacks I was referring to the sentence that says "_By default the path segment will match the key name_", as I thought that this is what you were referring to with "_how to use the key_". An example that shows how to use route elements inside of paths surely wouldn't hurt.

Comment: *"By default the path segment will match the key name"* to be honest, is not obvious to a beginner like myself. Yea. I am glad that you also think it's good to have another example in there.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that business logic wise, I was trying to create a nested resource.

Hence I will include my answer to another one of my own [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32032572/80353) about creating nested resource here.

------- ANSWER -----------

Do this in your `routes.php`

```
$routes->resources('Parents', function ($routes) {
    $routes->resources('Children');
});

$routes->resources('Children');
```

In `ChildrenController.php`,

```
protected function _prepareConditions() {
    $parentId = isset($this->request->params['parent_id']) ? $this->request->params['parent_id'] : null;

    if ($parentId == null) {
        return [];
    }

    return [
        'Children.parent_id' => $parentId
    ];
}

public function index()
{
    $conditions = $this->_prepareConditions();

    $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Parents'],
        'conditions' => $conditions
    ];
  // ... and so on
```

You will be able to do the following:

1. /parents/1/children
2. /parents/1/children.json
3. /children
4. /children.json

**Why this works?**

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-nested-resource-routes

tells us that basically to basically retrieve the parent id from the request params.

What it does not say explicitly is that, the routes will then reuse the basic 5 functions: index, add, view, delete, edit even when you nest them under a parent url.

**Why do you still have a separate resources route for the Children?**

This allows the /children and /children.json to work if you need them as well.

**What about add?**

I haven't tried that but I do not foresee any issues with using that as

1. /parents/1/children/add
2. /parents/1/children/add.json
3. /children/add
4. /children/add.json