# CakePHP 3 Passing Alphanumeric Parameter To Resource Routes

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to pass parameter in resource route. My routes.php has:

```
 $routes->resources('Products', [
        'map' => [
            'sku/:sku' => [
                'action' => 'viewBySku',
                'method' => 'GET',
            ]
        ]
        ]);
 });
```

And my control action is as follows:

```
public function viewBySku($sku) {
    die($sku);
}
```

After I execute the route the controller is generating a warning:

> Missing argument 1 for viewBySku()

What am I missing?

---

Edit:

I want to use alphanumeric value for the parameter. Most answers I've found are explaining how to pass integers only.

Comment: have you tried replacing `'sku/:sku'` with `'sku/:id'`? I don't think you need to match the param name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.x how do I include the params in the mapped resources?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33196167/cakephp-3-x-how-do-i-include-the-params-in-the-mapped-resources)

Comment: Yes, I've tried that originally. The problem is that I want to use alphanumeric value, rather than just an integer. I prefer not to use incremental ids for my api. Is there a way to convert :id to be alphanumeric?

Comment: You can use the `id` option to pass a custom regex,  [**by default**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#319-327) it matches [**integers and UUIDs**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/source-class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#32-44). See also **https://api.cakephp.org/3.3/class-Cake.Routing.RouteBuilder.html#_resources**. This will apply to all generated routes for that resource though. If you need more finegrained control for a specific, single route, then you're better off creating it manually via `connect()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is what I've ended up doing:

routes.php

```
$routes->resources('Products', [
    'map' => [
        'sku/:sku' => [
            'action' => 'viewBySku',
            'method' => 'GET',
        ]
    ]
]);
```

controller

```
public function viewBySku() {
    if (!$sku = $this->request->param('sku')) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Sku is missing");
    }

    die($sku);
}
```

Apparently, my variable is being passed to router but not to the controller's action.

---

### Other Solution

So after looking into resource routes I've found out that you can pass connect options to it:

```
$routes->resources('Products', [
    'map' => [
        'sku/:sku' => [
            'action' => 'viewBySku',
            'method' => 'GET',
        ]
    ],
    'connectOptions' => [
        'sku' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,10}',
        'pass' => ['sku', 'id']
    ]
]);
```

You can also modify the id's regex if you want to pass alphanumeric values to id parameter:

```
$routes->resources('Products', [
    'connectOptions' => [
        'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{2,10}'
    ]
]);
```